# How to hide some div when printing with this js code?

Tags: javascript, php, css

**I'm printing part of page with this code, how to not print some div???**

```
<script>
$.fn.extend({
    print: function() {
        var frameName = 'printIframe';
        var doc = window.frames[frameName];
        if (!doc) {
            $('<iframe>').hide().attr('name', frameName).appendTo(document.body);
            doc = window.frames[frameName];
        }
        doc.document.body.innerHTML = this.html();
        doc.window.print();
        return this;
    }
});
</script>
```

**button code(div id to print is with code cos id not static)**

```
<button onclick="$('#<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').print();">Print</button>
```

Printing code is working, no problem, but i can't hide some div from print, all css with **@media print** is working and hiding only when i print from right click-print but not working when i try to print with this code print button. How to hide some div?
To move out div from printable div inside - not possible.

div structure

```
<div class="some class"  id="some id" **that i'm printing with code**>
<div class="some class"  id="some id" **that i no need to print**>
<div class="some class"  id="some id" **part of printable div**>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**this one css not working when printing with button**

```
<style>
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
} 
</style>
```

Comment: you need to use @print media query and hide element using display:none in that media

Comment: already was trying to use class no-print from @media, working when printing with right button menu - print but not working when printing with code, printing with code just ignoring all class @ media print

Comment: I dont understand, do you want to hide elements on the screen or printed screen?

Comment: to hide on print, when printing with code, not with standart print menu, if i printing in standart way(right click-menu-print) css with media print is helping(div is hiden), but when i'm trying to print with button(that is with code) - all div is showing.

Comment: ok.. i got it.. as you are creating another iframe i guess you also need to add those @print in to that iframe.. as parent frames style does not apply to iframe.

Comment: Thank You, now the smallest problem left ;) how to do that, will be trying
can be code like this one?
```
$("#iframe").contents().find("#your_div_id").hide();
```

Comment: solved with adding id="print<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" to div that i need to print, problem was, that if i use satatic div id, than i print only one div, main div id is different each div and generated by id="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>", to get unique id to print and working one id to correct div - just add id="print<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" to div id ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved for **my situation**, by adding

```
id="print<?php echo $v['id']; ?>"
```

to div that i need to print, so all other will be hiden